# Exception code c0020001 on shutdown - how to determine which managed code function didn't run?

Tags: clr, windbg

I have a large C++/CLI application, which hosts 3rd-party binaries also written in C++/CLI. Sometime I get crashes on shutdown, with exception code `c0020001`(*). I know it means some CLI method is getting called after CLI was already shutdown.

**Question:** How can I find out which managed method was trying to get called? I found out in some cases (Stack trace 1 below), but not for others (Stack trace 2 below).

## What I tried

I captured full dumps of some such crashes, and the dumps show 2 different stacks traces (below).

- **Stack trace 1** has `clr!UMThunkStubRareDisableWorker` in it, and since it matches [this windbg guide](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/string-binding-is-invalid-exceptions-on-shutdown-o/476747) I was able to find out the managed method it was trying to call.
- **Stack trace 2** has different frame `clr!TheUMEntryPrestubWorker`, which inside calls `clr!CanRunManagedCode`. The above guide couldn't help me with this.

## Stack trace 1

```
00 00000000`2e09e520 00007ff8`712659bf     KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
01 00000000`2e09e600 00007ff8`70cd22e8     clr!UMThunkStubRareDisableWorker+0x3f
02 00000000`2e09e630 00007fff`ff20e4dc     clr!UMThunkStub+0x128
03 00000000`2e09e6c0 00007ff8`831bcf13     The3rdParty+0xe4dc
04 00000000`2e09e700 00007ff8`83130752     combase!<lambda_ef8a5b5bdab9c6b69f38e6b21c5d3987>::operator()+0xbb [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\stdid.cxx @ 1409] 
05 00000000`2e09e740 00007ff8`831307f5     combase!ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_ef8a5b5bdab9c6b69f38e6b21c5d3987> >+0xe [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\excepn.hxx @ 128] 
06 00000000`2e09e790 00007ff8`831bca36     combase!CStdIdentity::ReleaseCtrlUnk+0x81 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\stdid.cxx @ 1412] 
(...additional combase and rpcrt4 frames...)
```

## Stack trace 2

```
00 00000000`000cf500 00007ff8`71265833     KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
01 00000000`000cf5e0 00007ff8`70cd217e     clr!TheUMEntryPrestubWorker+0x43
02 00000000`000cf630 00007fff`fdcd47a4     clr!TheUMEntryPrestub+0x3e
03 00000000`000cf6a0 00007fff`fe07cc74     the3rdparty+0x47a4
04 00000000`000cf6d0 00007ff8`828d42d6     the3rdparty!DllUnregisterServer+0x11b694
05 00000000`000cf700 00007ff8`828d41fb     ucrtbase!<lambda_f03950bc5685219e0bcd2087efbe011e>::operator()+0xa6
06 00000000`000cf750 00007ff8`828d41b4     ucrtbase!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<<lambda_7777bce6b2f8c936911f934f8298dc43>,<lambda_f03950bc5685219e0bcd2087efbe011e> &,<lambda_3883c3dff614d5e0c5f61bb1ac94921c> >+0x3b
07 00000000`000cf780 00007fff`fdf7f475     ucrtbase!execute_onexit_table+0x34
08 00000000`000cf7b0 00007fff`fdf7f59a     the3rdparty!DllUnregisterServer+0x1de95
09 00000000`000cf7f0 00007ff8`7248ae44     the3rdparty!DllUnregisterServer+0x1dfba
0a 00000000`000cf850 00007ff8`755c1bad     mscoreei!CorDllMain+0x1b4
0b 00000000`000cf8d0 00007ff8`755c1c07     mscoree!ShellShim__CorDllMain+0xf5
0c 00000000`000cf910 00007ff8`85089a1d     mscoree!CorDllMain_Exported+0x37
0d 00000000`000cf940 00007ff8`850cdcda     ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x61
0e 00000000`000cf9b0 00007ff8`850cda8d     ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess+0x22a
0f 00000000`000cfac0 00007ff8`8479e3bb     ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0xad
10 00000000`000cfaf0 00007ff8`72471cd5     kernel32!ExitProcessImplementation+0xb
```

## Guide for Stack Trace 1

Based on [this windbg guide](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/string-binding-is-invalid-exceptions-on-shutdown-o/476747)

```
0:036> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 00000000`2e09e520 00007ff8`712659bf     KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
01 00000000`2e09e600 00007ff8`70cd22e8     clr!UMThunkStubRareDisableWorker+0x3f
02 00000000`2e09e630 00007fff`ff20e4dc     clr!UMThunkStub+0x128
(...)

0:036> .loadby sos clr    <<<<<<< Only worked for me on the repro machine - needs to have exact same build of CLR?
0:036> .sympath+ srv* ; .cordll -ve -u -l    <<< Seems to load everything

0:036> u clr!UMThunkStub L50
clr!UMThunkStub:
(...)
00007ff8`70cd22d9 4c895548        mov     qword ptr [rbp+48h],r10     <<<<<<<<<<< Storing r10, which has the method desc of the callback)
00007ff8`70cd22dd 498bcc          mov     rcx,r12
00007ff8`70cd22e0 498bd2          mov     rdx,r10
00007ff8`70cd22e3 e898365900      call    clr!UMThunkStubRareDisableWorker (00007ff8`71265980)
00007ff8`70cd22e8 4c8b5548        mov     r10,qword ptr [rbp+48h]     <<<<<<<<<<< RetAddr in stack

0:036> !dumpmd poi(poi(@rbp+48)+0x8)   <<<<<< Taking r10 from [@rbp+48], the look at internal data structure with details of where the method desc resides.
Method Name:  <Module>.ATL.CComObject<The3rdParty::ClassINeedToUninit>.__vecDelDtor(ATL.CComObject<The3rdParty::ClassINeedToUninit>*, UInt32)
Class:        00007ff812089678
MethodTable:  00007ff8120947b0
mdToken:      000000000600007e
Module:       00007ff812075010
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ff811f7b920
Transparency: Safe critical
```

(*) `c0020001` is `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION - Incorrect function`, although is sometimes incorrectly interpreted as `RPC_NT_INVALID_STRING_BINDING - The string binding is invalid`.

Comment: Have you tried `sfc /scannow` to check for corrupt system files?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I don't think `sfc` is relevant - I'm chasing a bug in my own application's code, not trying to fix a crashing application on my machine.

Comment: So, `The3rdParty` is actually your own application? Then, why don't you have symbols for it?

Comment: `The3rdParty` is an in-process 3rd-party plugin, for which I don't have symbols (I wish I did). I was hoping that getting the function name inside it would hint to the missing un-initialization method I was supposed to call